# The question marker か can only be used in polite questions right? Then why plain volitional can use it?

Tags: volitional-form, particle-か

今日は何をしようか。So is it a set rule that volitional form in plain (not using -ましょう) can use the question marker か?

Comment: Question the initial assumption. Is it true that the question marker か can only be used in polite questions.

Comment: Hint: the answer is no. か is universally used for questions, regardless of politeness or formality.

Answer (score 3):

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 166,
か can also be used in plain form.
Examples:
これは本だ。This is a book.
これは本か。 Is this a book? 
貴方は先生だ。You are a teacher.
貴方は先生か。 Are you a teacher?
In the examples above the だ drops and is replaced by か.

あの本は高い。That book is expensive.
あの本は高いか。 Is that book expensive?
私が話す。I speak.
私が話すか。 Do I speak?
In the examples above か is added at the end of the sentence.